# Windows user profiles behind symbolic links?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, terminal-server, windows-terminal-services, user-profile

We have a Windows terminal server under heavy load. We'd like to move some or all of its user profiles from the C: RAID-1, to the E: RAID-10.  Is it safe to do this using symbolic links, either one per user profile, or one for the whole Users folder?  I've read that it's not safe to do it for the whole Users folder at once, but not recently.  This is Server 2019.

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think this is safe. This may be the beggining of weird Windows behavior because that's probably not a use case tested by Microsoft.

Instead, I'd recommend taking a look at [User Profile Disks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-plan-secure-data-storage) or [FSLogix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fslogix/overview-what-is-fslogix) to properly store the profiles wherever you want in VHDX files (if you meet the licensing requirements I recommend using FSLogix)